# Issue with pdf creation using itext

Tags: java, itext

I have to edit an existing pdf file using itext in java. My problem is in the existing pdf it contains lots of pages. When inputting the page number of that existing pdf i have to edit the footer of that page to a new text and have to output only that page with edited footer page along with the page contents in that page. No need to output the remaining pages. Also the existing pdf is in A6 format and I have to change the output pdf to A4 format. How it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can split and merge PDF files using iText. That means, you need to split your original document into three parts and keep only the middle (required) part. You can also delete and add objects. That means you can find the footer object, delete it and and add a new object in its place. I do not think you would be able to change the format. Unless, you can create a brand new document in the target format and copy the objects from the source into the new document. Worth trying.

Comment: Modifying content with iText
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/modifying-pdf-documents.html